# MySQL SET user variable locks rows and doesn't obey REPEATABLE READ

Tags: mysql

I've encountered an undocumented behavior of "SET @my_var = (SELECT ..)" inside a transaction:

1. The first one is that it locks rows ( depends whether it is a unique index or not ).

Example -

```
START TRANSACTION;

SET @my_var = (SELECT id from table_name where id = 1);

select trx_rows_locked from information_schema.innodb_trx;
ROLLBACKL;
```

The output is 1 row locked, which is strange, it shouldn't gain a reading lock.

Also, the equivalent statement `SELECT id INTO @my_var` won't produce a lock.

It can lead to a deadlock in case of an `UPDATED` after the `SET` statement ( for 2 concurrent requests )

2. In REPEATABLE READ -

The `SELECT` inside the `SET` statement gets a new snapshot of the data, instead of using the original SNAPSHOT.

SESSION 1:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;                             
START transaction;         
SELECT data FROM my_table where id = 2; # Output : 2
```

SESSION 2:

```
UPDATE my_table set data = 3 where id = 2 ;
```

SESSION 1:

```
 SET @data = (SELECT data FROM my_table where id = 2);
 SELECT @data; # Output : 3, instead of 2
 ROLLBACK;
```

However, I would expect that `@data` will contain the original value from the first snapshot ( 2 ).

If I use `SELECT data into @data from my_table where id = 2` then I will get the expected value - 2;

Do you have an idea what is the source of the different behavior of `SET = (SELECT ..)` compared to `SELECT data INTO @var FROM ..` ?

Thanks.

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using.

Comment: MySQL version : 8.0.23

Comment: i could not find anything in the documentation, mine guess is `SET = (SELECT ..)` works outside the scope of the transaction but one would have to look into the MySQL source code to figure that out

Answer (score 0):

Correct — when you `SELECT` in a context where you're copying the results into a variable or a table, it implicitly works as if you had used a [locking read](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) `SELECT ... FOR SHARE`.

This means it places a shared lock on the rows examined, and it also means that the statement reads only the most recently committed version of rows, as if your transaction were in READ-COMMITTED isolation level.

I'm not sure why `SELECT ... INTO @var` does not do the same kind of implicit locking in MySQL 8.0. My memory is that in older versions of MySQL it did do locking in that query form. I've searched the manual for an explanation but I can't find one yet.

Other cases that implicitly lock the rows examined by `SELECT`, and therefore reads data as if you transaction is READ-COMMITTED:

- `INSERT INTO <table> SELECT ...`
- `UPDATE` or `DELETE` multi-table, even if you don't update or delete a given table, the rows joined become locked.
- `SELECT` inside a trigger